# React Native android build fails without an exception

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm trying to run a very simple React Native app on Android, but the build keeps on failing. The build is not giving any errors and the `run-ios` works just fine.

`$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html`

I'm running on OSX and trying to deploy the app on Samsung Galaxy S6 which is on `adb devices` list. Also tried to set ANDROID_HOME variable to my .bash_profile and update build tools, but those didn't help.

I'd be glad if someone could help me out with this one.

Answer (score 0):

change the gradle version to 1.2.3.

```
File android/build.gradle
modify this line: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

Comment: Tried to do that, but it didn't help on this case. Still having the same problem.

Comment: are you able to get a shell on the device with 'adb shell' ? Is usb-debugging enabled on the phone?

Comment: 'adb shell' works fine and  and usb-debugging is enabled and the mac is authorized on the device. And I'm actually able to run native android projects and Cordova projects on the phone. So the React Native is the only framework I'm having issues with.